# How to hande iOS MVC when there is a complex view hierarchy

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, model-view-controller

I'm creating an app with the following view hierarchy:

- Main View

  - View1

    - UIlabel
    - UICollectionView
  - View2

    - UILabel
    - UIScrollView

      - UITableView
      - UITableView
    - PageControl

This probably isn't too complex of a view heirarchy, but currently I only have one view controller for the main view. View1 and View2 are custom views.

View1 is the delegate and datasource for the UICollectionView.

View2 has a custom UIScrollView and is the delegate. This custom UIScrollView is the delegate and datasource for the UITableView.

Now since I have two UITableViews as pages of the UIScrollView I'm fixing to hit a design wall where this isn't going to work.

I wanted to ask what view's( including the UICollectionView and UITableViews ) should have their own UIViewControllers?

They are all on the screen at the same time( except for the different pages of the UIScrollView).

Answer (score 0):

All of this is possible to do within one `UIViewController`, implementing  `UIScrollViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDatasource`, `UITableViewDelegate`, `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDataSource`, but this will give you a large file that will be complex to maintain. I would suggest looking into [ContainerViewControllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html).

In you scenario, I'd suggest you to create a view controller for each of your child views on level one. If you add these view controllers as childviewcontrollers to your MainViewController, you should be able to communicate across the views...

Also, remember that `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` passes a pointer to the tableview it is asking you for data, so if you compare the tableView-pointer passed by the delegate method to you view controllers properties, you should be able to solve both tableviews within one delegate and datasource.